# Index out of bound error for comparing adjacent numbers in list

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

List item

```
for i in num_list:
    if(i < len(num_list) - 1 and num_list[i] == num_list[i+1]):
        count = count + 1 
    else:
        count = count
```

I'm getting index out of bound error in if condition. What is the error? I have used len in if condition

Comment: Please take the time to correctly format and indent your code before posting - especially with python.

Comment: `i` is not the index of the elemnt, but the element itself. Use `for i in range(len(num_list)):`. Also, `else: count = count` is pretty pointless.

Comment: About the `i < len`: The error could still arise if `i` (remember: the element, not the index) is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `i` value is not the indices of the list, it is the actual items in the list that are being iterated through.

Your else statement in the loop is also not necessary since it does not change anything.

I think this accomplishes what you are looking for:

```
count = 0
num_list = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1]

for i in range(len(num_list) - 1):
    if(num_list[i] == num_list[i + 1]):
        count += 1 

print(count)
# Output: 2
```

`range(len(num_list) - 1)` is going to loop through all indices except for the last one in the list. So the if check to make sure it is not out of bounds is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in num_list:
```

does not iterate over the length/range, instead if iterates over the values.
For example

```
num_list = [3,4,1,5,3]
for i in num_list:
    print(i)
```

would output

```
3
4
1
5
3
```

Instead, you want to iterate over the index in which case your foor loop should look like this:

```
for i in range(len(num_list)):
```

where the following code

```
num_list = [3,4,1,5,3]
for i in num_list:
    print(i)
```

would output

```
0
1
2
3
4
```